# UITableView with section Filter for json

Tags: xcode, uitableview, predicate

[image]

Expected result

[image]
I have below json response, but I am unable to filter data keeping section with **user_name**

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "result": {
        "Section 0": [
            {
                "id": "240",
                "user_name": "Raman ",

            },
            {
                "id": "241",
                "user_name": "Ram ",

            },
            {
                "id": "243",
                "user_name": "Ramesh ",

            },
            {
                "id": "246",
                "user_name": "Angelia ",
            }
        ],
        "Section 1": [
            {
                "id": "240",
                "user_name": "Rohit ",
      
            },
            {
                "id": "241",
                "user_name": "Robin ",
           
            },
            {
                "id": "246",
                "user_name": "Angelia ",
      
            }
        ],
        "Section 2": [
            {
                "id": "240",
                "user_name": "Raman ",
            
            },
            {
                "id": "242",
                "user_name": "Nick ",

            }
        ]
    },
    "message": ""
}
```

**Code I used for general search in any tableview with normal json**

```
    let searchpredicate:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@",searchText)
 filterdata  = self.responseArray.filter{searchpredicate.evaluate(with: $0)} as! [[String : Any]]
```

Comment: What is `responseArray`?

Comment: response array having the above json on which filter need to be apply

Comment: The *above json* is a dictionary.

Comment: please check I have parse the dynamic key section 0 .... etc as my section header and inside array to be used for cells, as shown in pic